# How to plot the implicit function $y^2=x^3/(a-x)$?

Tags: graphing-functions

How can I plot this implicit function: $$y^2=\dfrac{x^3}{a-x}$$

Should I use a polar coordinate transformation?

Comment: I've copyedited your question; please check that I didn't change the intended meaning.

Comment: Why don't you use a Math software?

Comment: You should specify where you want to plot this function, as in Mathematica, or Maple, or on your TI, or just as a rough sketch - that will make the answers more relevant.

Comment: sorry.
I am not good at speaking English.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pizvo1uigj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another command via Maple for doing that plot for any certain value of $a$:

> $[>$ *with(plots):*
>
> $[>$ *implicitplot*({seq($x^3/(a-x)-y^2 = 0$, $a = 1 .. 14$)}, $x = 0 .. 10, y = -20 .. 20$, *numpoints* $= 20000$);

Above I chose $a=14$, you can choose it $40$. :)

[image]

Comment: That's an incredibly beautiful graph!

Answer (score 1):

You can just rewrite it as $$y = \pm \sqrt{\dfrac{x^3}{a-x}}$$ and plot the positive and negative branches of that (which will be just mirror images of each other).  Here's a quick example I did in Maple, with $a = 1$:

[image: Plot of y^2=x^3/(1-x) made using Maple 13]

Note that, as the plot shows, your equation only has real solutions in the range $0 \le x < a$ (or $a < x \le 0$ if $a < 0$).  Outside that range, $\frac{x^3}{a-x}$ will be negative (or undefined, for $x = a$), so $y$ would need to be imaginary.

In principle, you could also solve the original equation for $x$ as a function of $y$ and plot that.  However, that entails solving the cubic polynomial $x^3+y^2x-y^2a=0$, and while there are [straightforward methods for doing that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Roots_of_a_cubic_function), the result will not be particularly pretty.

Comment: I really appreciate for your prompt arrengiment.